# Update field on SELECT

Tags: mysql

When I select a record from a table using SELECT how can I UPDATE one of that record's fields in the same statement? It's basically the combination of the following two statements:

```
SELECT value FROM items WHERE = id ='123'
UPDATE items SET found=1 WHERE id='123'
```

To mark that record as found.

Edit...

Would SELECT FOR UPDATE be appropriate in this instance?

Comment: So you want to set the Found field once you have retrieved the value? Is that right?

Comment: Why do you need them combined?  If you haven't changed any records, they will not have changed (within this transaction).

Comment: I would be tempted to do it the other way round. Update all the records with a marker (probably on another table linked to the unique id), and then do the select for the marked records

Comment: I cannot imagine why you'd want to do that. However, it is two statements and cannot be done in fewer.

Comment: why not just do `UPDATE items SET found=1 WHERE id='123'`? Since this will only update rows where `id` is equal to `123`?

Comment: It's a consideration for concurrency. I don't want another process to be read this record if it's already read. Don't know if this would do anything to achieve this though.

Comment: Unless you are trying to prevent another process from updating `value`, the outcome will be the same, though as @Kickstart suggests, flagging early will possibly prevent more reads (just hope *your* process doesn't crash before *you* read it).

Comment: @dave88 - In that case you should use a transaction: `START TRANSACTION; UPDATE items SET found=1 WHERE id='123'; COMMIT;`

Comment: I forgot to mention these records marked as 'found' will be deleted by an event scheduler - that's what I'm ultimately trying to achieve. I just don't want another process to read a record which is already being read. The select is used to obtain the the value (which is returned).

Comment: In which case mark them as being processed, and once processed mark them as ready to be be deleted.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be the same as setting found=1 and telling other sessions to skip records with found=1?

Comment: No, as multiple copies of the same script might run at the same time, and you want to batch those up so the same script marks them as found (and can thus process the ones it marked as found). You do the update first to mark the ones you want to process (ie, found = 1, or found = some unique session identifier), and then just select those which have been marked.

Comment: OK, I'll definitely look to doing this.